# Can I generate a final doc with a first doc generate with OPENTBS?

Tags: opentbs

I am creating an app, which permits to generate documents. For this, I am using `OPENTBS`.

I arrive to generate a document but form this first document generate, I don't arrive to generate a second file.

I tried to write 'test' for the first document generate but in the final document, it doesn't change.

This code replace in the template and write in the first file generated :

```
$form2[$categorie][$tache][$j][$champ] = '[onshow.'.$categorie.$tache.$champ.$j.$i.';ope=changepic;tagpos=after]';
                                                            $image[$categorie][$tache][$j][$champ] = '[onshow.'.$categorie.$tache.$champ.$j.$i.';ope=changepic;tagpos=after]';

For the file final : $$chaine = $request->get('img')[0][$cat][$tache][$champ][$i];
```

Like I used to onshow : `$$chaine contains $categorie.$tache.$champ.$j...`

I want to know if it is possible to generate a final from the first file generated.

Answer (score 0):

It is actually possible to use a merged document as a template for another merging.
This is beacause both the template and the merged documents are valid DOCX documents.

The problem you have probably because of the TBS default behavior for protecting merged data.

For security reason, merged data in the template are protected by replacind `[` characters with their XML/HTML special char instead. This prevent from inserting automating merging field.

In order to avoid this protection, you can use parameter `protect=no` in the TBS field that you receive code.

[See the manual about parameter protect](https://www.tinybutstrong.com/manual.php#html_field_prm_protect)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I found a solution : I succeded to make it in the first file generated.